# Why is Gradle not including my dependencies when I specifically state them?

Tags: java, gradle

We are retrofitting an existing web app to include SOAP services using JBoss 6 EAP and CXF. My problem is that, even though I *explicitly* state I want certain dependencies included in my .war file (using "compile {dependency}"), they are not included. It appears to be related to other libraries.

Trying to be a good do-bee, I listed all the cxf dependencies as 'providedCompile' since JBoss EAP already includes them in the modules directory:

```
providedCompile "org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:2.6.8"
providedCompile "org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:2.6.8"
providedCompile "org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:2.6.8"
providedCompile "org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:2.6.8"
providedCompile "org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:2.6.8"
providedCompile "org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:2.6.8"
providedCompile "org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:2.6.8"
providedCompile "org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:2.6.8"
providedCompile "org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-common:2.6.8"
providedCompile "org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-validator:2.6.8"
providedCompile "org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-core:2.6.8"
providedCompile "org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-databinding-jaxb:2.6.8"
```

For example, I need dom4j. I know I need it because I see the ClassNotFoundExceptions at startup.

So I add this to my dependencies:

```
compile "dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1"
```

No joy. That is, until I change all the above 'providedCompile' statements to 'compile'.

I am still working on producing a simplified example for posting here, but has anyone else see odd behavior like this? Why would one 'providedCompile' dependency *block* another 'compile' dependency from being included in a .war file? Why must I duplicate libraries in my .war that are already provided by the container?

Comment: Have you checked that the library was not in the war, or do you assume it isn't there because of the ClassNotFoundException?

Comment: I verified the library was not in the war by listing the contents of the .war

Answer (score 1):

Gradle assumes that all dependencies of the `providedCompile` configuration (which includes direct *and* transitive dependencies) are available in the target environment, and hence doesn't include them in the War. `dom4j` is likely a transitive `providedCompile` dependency. If you want to express that only direct `providedCompile` dependencies are available in the target environment (i.e. the ones explicitly listed in the build script), you can set `configurations.providedCompile.transitive = false`, or selectively use the `@jar` notation (e.g. `providedCompile "org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml@jar:2.6.8"`).

To check which `providedCompile` dependency(s) drag in `dom4j`, run `gradle dependencyInsight --configuration providedCompile --dependency dom4j`.

Comment: Thanks; I had missed the 'dependencyInsight' task. 

After trying it (and the transitive flag) though, I'm no closer to resolving my issue.

My issue is that dom4j (for example; I have at least 5 that are causing problems) is *not* included in the war. DependencyInsight tells me why it *should* be there, but not why it was omitted.

Comment: Have you followed my advice? If you run `dependencyInsight` for `providedCompile`, it will tell you what will be *excluded*.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't yield anything. Sorry for implying I did not try it.

"gradle dependencyInsight --configuraion providedCompile --dependency dom4j" returns:
No dependencies matching given input were found in configuration ':providedCompile'

This makes sense because dom4j is listed as 'compile'. If I change it to 'providedCompile' the same command returns:

:dependencyInsight
dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1 (forced)
\--- providedCompile

(it is forced because I am trying to force a given version)

My base frustration is that my explicitly indicated dependencies are not included.

Comment: If your explicitly indicated dependency was also a transitive `providedCompile` dependency, this would be expected. If not, I'd need a reproducible example to investigate.